# caliburn Querying itemsource on action

Tags: c#, xaml

So I have an Autocompletebox that's link to Businesses. I'm Looking for an appropriate action to trigger the caliburn requeries. So far I tried MouseClick, Which works Perfectly! but if the mouse drags over typed characters it actually crashes. Next I implemented KeyDown and sometimes the database just slows down the performance. Any recommendations to what it should be changed to?

What I've Tried so far:

```
public void UpdateCollection()
{
    using (var ctx =  DB.GET())
    {
        Clients.Clear()
        Clients.AddRange(ctx.Businesses)
    }
 }
```

xaml side:

```
<telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyDown] = [UpdateCollection]" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}">
```

Maybe an option is through a template or style?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting a timing mechanism in place after the key down so that it doesnt requery every single time you press a key?  something like this:

```
    private string _text;
    public async void UpdateCollection()
    {
        _text = searchtextvaluehere;
        await Task.Delay(200);
        if (_text == searchtextvaluehere)
        {
            using (var ctx =  DB.GET())
            {
                Clients.Clear();
                Clients.AddRange(ctx.Businesses);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not 100% sure how the telerik autocomplete works but i have used something like the above for delayed search before. Hopefully it can help you out.